# Массовая рассылка с помощью Telegram бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiohttp

Нужно, чтобы Telegram бот, зная id пользователей,которые он получает через `from Users import list`, мог отправлять им одно и то же сообщение. Желательно, чтобы пользователи не могли контактировать с ботом.

Comment: Это можно сделать через обычный цикл. Наверняка id пользователей у Вас будут записаны через лист/массив. НО нужно, чтобы все пользователи заранее запустили бота, иначе никак. А чтобы они не могли контактировать с ботом, игнорируйте все их сообщения :)

Comment: Спасибо за то,что откликнулись.В принципе,я так и думал,но решил уточнить

Comment: Еще избегайте именовать переменные и функции как типы данных в Python (`from Users import list`), это может принести много головной боли

Answer (score 0):

На примере aiogram

```
from Users import list

async def notify_users(message):
    for user in list:
        await bot.send_message(user, message)
```

p.s. Бот не сможет отправить сообщение пользователям, которые ему ни разу не писали